# How to host html files like css and javascript files

Tags: javascript, css, html, blogger

I have uploaded some files to google drive and got the link sucessfully.
But now i want to implement those files on blogger.

If i implement those files on blogger look like below

example css file extension

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://googledrive.com/host/0B4n9GL3eVuV-TkphMkc3SFR2Slk" />
```

example javascript file extension

```
<script src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B4n9GL3eVuV-eVYwLXBrTlZrVDg' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

How can i use html file should i use

Comment: Just one question I have. What exactly is the question here?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet type="text/css"   <script src= type='text/javascript'> ok like if we want to add external html file what we use

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal _How to host html files like css and javascript files_, but i didnt understand it.

Comment: Are you looking to keep your html (html page) on google drive and include in your blog post as a template or a part of your blog? Just like the answer below using iframes

Comment: we use IFRAMES as answered below

Comment: for example if we add css in notepad save with css and javascript save with .js and with html .html and css and javascript have to host links but how can i get host link from html file i need this 
https://googledrive.com/host/0B6AINFhwU0Z4aWZneC1jTWdsQkk to host but it is html file how can i use with <script or <link

Comment: is iframe right for this i man can i do it with iframe https://googledrive.com/host/0B6AINFhwU0Z4aWZneC1jTWdsQkk  .....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you maybe talking about iframes?

Comment: this is javascript code 
https://googledrive.com/host/0B6AINFhwU0Z4Z3lCTUFIb0JRZXc this is css code 
https://googledrive.com/host/0B6AINFhwU0Z4eTdLcmFjQ2JVVEE this is html code 
https://googledrive.com/host/0B6AINFhwU0Z4aWZneC1jTWdsQkk  html i know to host css and java script as i said above but not html that is the problem

Comment: Well, the only answer would be iframes since I do not see the point of linking any html files if it isn't for getting its structure. Could you say me what would you like to link in this html file? How would you like to use the content of the html file?

Comment: Well then if you want to take its structure, you should use iframes. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp